# awk sed grep to extract patten with special characters

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I am trying to understant the switchs and args in awk and sed

For instance, to get the number next to nonce in the line form the file response.xml:

```
WWW-Authenticate: ServiceAuth realm="WinREST", nonce="1828HvF7EfPnRtzSs/h10Q=="
```

I use by suggestion of another member

```
nonce=$(sed -nE 's/.*nonce="([^"]+)"/\1/p' response.xml)
```

to get the numbers next to the word idOperation in the line below I was trying :

```
idOper=$(sed -nE 's/.*idOperation="([^"]+)"/\1/p' zarph_response.xml)
```

line to extract the number:

```
{"reqStatus":{"code":0,"message":"Success","success":true},"idOperation":"185-16-6"}
```

how do I get the 185-16-6 ?

and if the data to extract has no ""
like the 1 next to operStatus ?

```
{"reqStatus":{"code":0,"message":"Success","success":true},"operStatus":1,"amountReceived":0,"amountDismissed":0,"currency":"EUR"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"\"" '/idOperation/{print $(NF-1)}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In `sed` following may help you on same.

```
sed '/idOperation/s/\(.*:\)"\([^"]*\)\(.*\)/\2/'   Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** In case you want to get the digit after string `operStatus` then following may help you on same.

```
awk 'match($0,/operStatus[^,]*/){;print substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Done.
And for the second case, for the number without "", I have tried the some code with the new pattern and can't get the 1.

Comment: @PedroCaldeira, sure. check my EDIT solution now and let me know if this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Using grep perl-style regexes

```
grep -oP "nonce=\"\K(.*)?(?=\")" Input_file
grep -oP "idOperation\":\"\K(.*)?(?=\")" Input_file
```

If the input is json you can use jq

```
jq .idOperation Input_file
```